# Code First - Entity Framework - Inherited type not displaying all properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a code first entity Model with 3 objects that create 2 tables/entites:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedCustomer : Customer
{
    [Required]
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasOptional(e => e.AddressList).WithMany();
}
```

As you can see, the Extended customer inherits from Customer and adds another property.

When it generates the tables, there is just a Customer and PhoneNumber table (no Extended customer), and the extended property is correctly in the Customer table.

So far so good.

(Also you'll notice that the phone number table returns a customer, not an extended customer. That is because the model does not necessarily have an extended customer and does not need to know that level of concreteness)

However, when I navigate through context.Customer.First() the extended property is not there in the customer object.

How do I get it there?

Thanks, James

Comment: how is the `context.Customer`defined?

Comment: I think thats part of the problem.....

The DB context should create the entity with the extended properties in it. 
Before I was using 
       public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

instead of 

       public DbSet<ExtendedCustomer> Customers { get; set; }


So now the extended properties are successfully pulled into my Context.Customer.First() instance.

However, when I go Context.Addresses.First().Customer.First() the extended properties are not there!!

Comment: Then, if your `Address` contains a plain `Customer` you'll end up with the same problem. You can try a type cast or use `ExtendedCustomer` in you address table.

Comment: Right, we specifically need to return a Customer because not all projects will use the extensions. I'm just wondering if there's a way to declare the return type as the entity rather than the data object?

Comment: You can, but then you will loose the strong-typing; trust me: that's not what you want. An alternative would be an extension method. But this cannot be applied to properties (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx). An extension method is possible,but will be 'quite a brick' to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not there because, I assume, `context.Customer.First()` is returning a `Customer` type (even if the instance is `ExtendedCustomer`, the static compiler has no way to ensure that)

Depending on what you need to do you can either add `ExtendedCustomers` to your `context` or use `context.Customers.OfType<ExtendedCustomer>()`

Comment: It's not there because a collection of a type can only return objects of that type. Even if there are actually subtypes of it inside it. You will have to cast it to the object subtype after/while you retrieve it. DbSets have the ``OfType`` extension method you mentioned that does this for us.

Answer (score 0):

Since Address.Customer is of Customer type, it will always return a Customer even if it points to ExtendedCustomer data. If it was saved as an ExtendedCustomer, it's properties are there, you just have to type cast it to access them.

```
var cust = Context.Addresses.First().Customer.First();
var extCust = cust as ExtendedCustomer;
if (extCust != null)
{
    // It's an ExtendedCustomer, you can access it's properties now. ;)
}
```

Also, this might have useful information for you: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx